# how to cache all the data records in mapper and process them at the end?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a map-reduce job in which the mapper is in charge of clustering data records. When a data record is read, I add it to a `list`. How to know when all the data records are read that I can start clustering the `list`?

Answer (score 0):

The `Mapper` interface provides a `cleanup` method that gets called when a task is finished.  You could use that as a hook to trigger whatever additional logic you need to perform with the `list` of objects.  I have to ask though, why not use a `Reducer` task to perform this processing?